Attribute 'config-file' is missing from element 'server'
I'm new to xml and am trying to deploy a spring application on tomact7.
When i have started the server 'tomcat7',I'm getting this error as below:
"Attribute 'config-file' is missing from element 'server'"
Also please find the image attached which has errors that i got.
Error image in eclipse
This is my mbean-servers.xml file:

 -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE servers SYSTEM "mbean-servers.dtd"> -->
                                        
<servers xmlns="http://www.appdynamics.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.appdynamics.com mbean-servers.xsd">
<server mbean-server-name="WebSphere"
        mbean-name-pattern="WebSphere:*,type=Server,j2eeType=J2EEServer"
        version-attribute="platformVersion"
        version-startsWith="7"/>
<server mbean-server-name="WebSphere"
        mbean-name-pattern="WebSphere:*,type=Server,j2eeType=J2EEServer"
        version-attribute="platformVersion"
        version-startsWith="6"/>
<server mbean-server-name="JBoss_4"
        mbean-name-pattern="jboss.management.local:j2eeType=J2EEServer,name=Local"
        version-attribute="serverVersion"
        version-startsWith="4"/>
<server mbean-server-name="JBoss_5"
        mbean-name-pattern="jboss.management.local:j2eeType=J2EEServer,name=Local"
        version-attribute="serverVersion"
        version-startsWith="5"/>
<server mbean-server-name="JBoss_6"
        mbean-name-pattern="jboss.management.local:j2eeType=J2EEServer,name=Local"
        version-attribute="serverVersion"
        version-startsWith="6"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Tomcat_5.5"
        mbean-name-pattern="Catalina:type=Server"
        version-attribute="serverInfo"
        version-startsWith="Apache Tomcat/5.5"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Tomcat_6.0"
        mbean-name-pattern="Catalina:type=Server"
        version-attribute="serverInfo"
        version-startsWith="Apache Tomcat/6.0"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Tomcat_7"
        mbean-name-pattern="Catalina:type=Server"
        version-attribute="serverInfo"
        version-startsWith="Apache Tomcat/7"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Sun GlassFish_2.1"
        mbean-name-pattern="com.sun.appserv:j2eeType=J2EEServer,name=server,category=runtime"
        version-attribute="serverVersion"
        version-startsWith="Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1"/>
<server mbean-server-name="WebLogic_10"
        mbean-server-lookup-string="java:comp/jmx/runtime"
        mbean-name-pattern="com.bea:*,Type=ServerRuntime"
        version-attribute="WeblogicVersion"
        version-startsWith="WebLogic Server 10"/>
<server mbean-server-name="WebLogic_9"
        mbean-server-lookup-string="java:comp/jmx/runtime"
        mbean-name-pattern="com.bea:*,Type=ServerRuntime"
        version-attribute="WeblogicVersion"
        version-startsWith="WebLogic Server 9"/>
<server mbean-server-name="ActiveMQ" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.activemq:*"/>
<server mbean-server-name="HornetQ" mbean-name-pattern="org.hornetq:*"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Apache Solr" mbean-name-pattern="solr:*"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Apache Cassandra 0.7.0" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.cassandra.net:*"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Apache Cassandra 0.7.0" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.cassandra.db:*"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Apache Cassandra 0.7.0" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.cassandra.request:*"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Apache Cassandra 0.7.0" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.cassandra.internal:*"/>
<server mbean-server-name="Oracle Coherence 3.7.1"
        mbean-name-pattern="Coherence:type=Cluster"
        version-attribute="Version"
        version-startsWith="3.7.1"/>
<!-- If you are using Platform MBean server to report activemq metrics then you may uncomment the following line.
-->
<!--
<server mbean-server-name="Platform" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.activemq:*" config-file="servers\activemq-5.3.2-jmx-config.xml" />
-->

<!-- If your app publishes custom jmx metrics to platform jmx server then  you may modify the platform-jmx-config.xml[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/xqmDLwiI.png)
and update the mbean-name-pattern in the following line to start recording your metrics by appdynamics agent
-->

<!--
<server mbean-server-name="Platform" mbean-name-pattern="com.foo.myjmx:*" config-file="servers\platform-jmx-config.xml" />
-->


That error message means that your <server ... /> elements need a config-file attribute.
If you compare one of your <server ... /> elements with one of the samples you can see it:
<!-- your element -->
<server mbean-server-name="ActiveMQ" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.activemq:*"/>

<!-- sample element that is in a comment section later on -->
<server mbean-server-name="Platform" mbean-name-pattern="org.apache.activemq:*" config-file="servers\activemq-5.3.2-jmx-config.xml" />

According to the mbean-servers.dtd that I found online the config-file attribute is required, i.e. you must include it in every <server ... /> element.
